# Apply rounded corners to arc created with UIBezierPath

Tags: objective-c, uibezierpath

I am working on a circular progress bar that i've created using UIBezierPath. The progress bar looks like the following picture:

[image]

My question is: how to make the edge of the arc rounded and not rectangular?

The code i used to draw the arc looks like is:

```
 // Draw the arc with bezier path
        int radius = 100;

        arc = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        arc.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(100, 50) radius:radius startAngle:M_PI endAngle:M_PI/150 clockwise:YES].CGPath;
        arc.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame)-radius,
                                    CGRectGetMidY(self.view.frame)-radius);
        arc.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
        arc.strokeColor = [UIColor purpleColor].CGColor;
        arc.cornerRadius = 0.5;
        arc.lineWidth = 6;

        [self.view.layer addSublayer:arc];

        // Animation of the progress bar
        drawAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
        drawAnimation.duration            = 5.0; // "animate over 10 seconds or so.."
        drawAnimation.repeatCount         = 1.0;  // Animate only once..
        drawAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;   // Remain stroked after the animation..
        drawAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
        drawAnimation.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:10.0f];
        drawAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
        [arc addAnimation:drawAnimation forKey:@"drawCircleAnimation"];
```

I tried to use `arc.cornerRadius` but it seemed to return nothing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Granit

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Set `lineCapStyle` to `kCGLineCapRound` (On the bezier path) to draw the ends of the lines with a round edge.

You can also set the `lineCap` on the shape layer to do the same thing.

Comment: @Grangji In your example it's still not working. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: It should be set on CAShapeLayer, not on UIBezierPath.

Answer (score 8):

To make corner as round you can use this.

```
arc.lineCap = @"round";
```

Comment: Use the proper constant equivalent! `kCGLineCapRound`

Comment: @Warpling i tried using kCGLineCapRound but it didn't worked. with "round" it worked. Any idea why kCGLineCapRound is not working?

Comment: @RajTandel I'm not sure. Are you sure you want to set `lineCap` and not `lineCapStyle`?

Comment: use this : layer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound;   [document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cashapelayer/1521905-linecap)

Answer (score 2):

The swift equivalent is:

```
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(…)
circlePath.lineCapStyle = .round
```

Comment: If there a tag `swift` in the question or anything related too?