# Not able to round caps in UIBezierPath Arc even with kCGLineCapRound

Tags: ios, objective-c, rounded-corners, uibezierpath

I am not able to display rounded caps on my Arc created using UIBezierPath. It's still perfectly squared regardless I set kCGLineCapRound or not.

This topic should be same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20666033/apply-rounded-corners-to-arc-created-with-uibezierpath), however solution is not working.

Here is the example code I have in viewWillAppear (for test purposes only):

```
int radius = 100;
CAShapeLayer *arc = [CAShapeLayer layer];
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(100, 50) radius:radius startAngle:M_PI endAngle:M_PI/150 clockwise:YES];
path.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;

arc.path = path.CGPath;
arc.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame)-radius, CGRectGetMidY(self.view.frame)-radius);
arc.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
arc.strokeColor = [UIColor purpleColor].CGColor;
arc.lineWidth = 10.0f;
arc.cornerRadius = 3.0f;
```

Here is how it looks:

[image: whyy]

I am helpless so I would appreciate any help. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use the `lineCap` property of the `CAShapeLayer` rather than the `lineCapStyle` of the path.

```
arc.lineCap = kCALineCapRound;
```

If you are calling the path's `stroke` method (e.g. if you're doing this in `drawRect` or manually drawing in a `UIGraphicsContext`) then set attributes like the cap or join styles in the `UIBezierPath`. But when using `CAShapeLayer`, the attributes are set on the shape layer, not the path.